# Chunk size appears on Browser page

Tags: chunked-encoding

I'm implementing a small web server into a wifi micro.  To aid in development and test, I have ported it to Windows console program.

I use chunked transfer processing. The following is what shows up on the browser:

0059

Hello World

0

The 59 is the hex size of the chunk and the 0 is the chunked terminating size

This is the data captured via wireshark:

This is the first message I send which are the headers

```
0000   48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d  HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
0010   0a 53 65 72 76 65 72 3a 20 54 72 61 6e 73 66 65  .Server: Transfe
0020   72 2d 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a 20 63 68 75 6e  r-Encoding: chun
0030   6b 65 64 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70  ked..Content-Typ
0040   65 3a 20 74 65 78 74 2f 68 74 6d 6c 0d 0a 43 61  e: text/html..Ca
0050   63 68 65 2d 43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20 6d 61 78  che-Control: max
0060   2d 61 67 65 3d 33 36 30 30 2c 20 6d 75 73 74 2d  -age=3600, must-
0070   72 65 76 61 6c 69 64 61 74 65 0d 0a 0d 0a        revalidate....
```

The next block is the chunked data

```
0000   30 30 35 39 0d 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 65  0059..<html>.<he
0010   61 64 3e 3c 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 57 65 62 20 53 65  ad><title>Web Se
0020   72 76 65 72 3c 2f 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 0a 3c 2f 68  rver</title>.</h
0030   65 61 64 3e 0a 3c 62 6f 64 79 3e 0a 3c 68 31 3e  ead>.<body>.<h1>
0040   48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 3c 2f 68 31 3e  Hello World</h1>
0050   0a 3c 2f 62 6f 64 79 3e 3c 2f 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0d  .</body></html>.
0060   0a 30 0d 0a 0d 0a                                .0....
```

The chunked values are being displayed on both Chrome and IE.

Can anyone see an issue with my data that would cause the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I mistakenly remove the server name so now the browser is taking the transfer encoding as the server name and does not understand the chunked message size -- it thinks its just data to display.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer .. exactly where did you remove and add the server name ?

Comment: I also have this issue and can't figure out what this answer means. Please elaborate.